# Rails console (in docker-compose) hangs when I try to paste a string with an extended character such as "Vötest"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker-compose, irb, extended-ascii

On my Mac:

1. Copy the string `n = "Vötest"` to my clipboard from my code editor (Sublimetext 3.2.2)
2. Launch Rails console

```
    rails c
    irb(main):001:0>
```

3. Attempt to paste the string to the console, 100% of the time console hangs as soon as it encounters the extended character... won't echo anything typed except ^c or return cause a  new line, but stays hung until I terminate my terminal window.

```
    irb(main):001:0> n = "V    <hangs here >
```

I'm running Rails 5.2.6.2. inside docker-compose.

If I open an irb session (not rails c, not dockerized) I can paste the string. So I'm not sure if it is Rails console or docker causing the issue since I can't 'get' to my Rails console outside docker.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to use Rails console to do some experimenting with strings that contain extended characters?